# A view get "mysteriously" stripped off its tag

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a set of `ToggleButton`s and a `ViewPager` in which I'd like to add a view when a toggle is clicked and changes its state to checked.

I managed to do that, and now I'd like to remove a view associated with a `ToggleButton` when it's being unchecked. I tried to do that by setting tags on the views before adding them to the ViewPager.

Here's some code:

```
        ((ToggleButton) ((RelativeLayout) mDaysTableLayoutTableRow.getChildAt(i)).getChildAt(0)).setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked) {                     
                    if(mDaysViewPager == null) {
                        mDaysViewPager = new ViewPager(getActivity());
                        mLinearLayoutRoot.addView(mDaysViewPager, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                        mPagerAdapter = new DaysPagerAdapter();
                        mDaysViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
                    }

                    if (mDaysViewPager != null) {
                        ScrollView mView = new ScrollView(getActivity());
                        TextView mTV = new TextView(getActivity());
                        mTV.setText(buttonView.getText());
                        mView.addView(mTV);
                        mView.setTag(buttonView.getText());
                        Log.i("tags:", "" + mView.getTag()); //works
                        mPagerAdapter.addView(mView);
                        mPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                } else if(!isChecked) {
                    mPagerAdapter.removeView(mDaysViewPager, buttonView.getText());
                    mPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });
```

`removeView()` and `addView()`:

```
  public void removeView(ViewPager pager, Object tag)
  {
    pager.setAdapter(null);

    for(int i = 0; i < views.size(); i++) {
        Log.i("tags:", "view: " + view.getTag() + ", func: " + tag); // Returns "view: null, func: xxx" where xxx is the correct tag
        if(view.getTag() == tag) {
            Log.i("tags:", "in"); // never fires
            views.remove(i);
        }
    }

    pager.setAdapter(this);
  }


  public int addView(View v, int position)
  {
      views.add(position, v);
      return position;
  }
```

As you can see, apparently the views don't have a tag set when I try to remove them.
I have no idea why the tag couldn't work. It doesn't get reset as far as my code goes, nor does the view passed get recreated or deleted.

If so what could be the source of this problem and how could I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot compare string contents using `==`.  `String` is an object, and the equality operator tests whether 2 objects are the same object, not whether their contents are the same.  Instead, use `.equals()`.

```
if(view.getTag().equals(tag))
```

You should also learn how to use the debugger and step through your code, you would then see that the tag is still there, and therefore, that the `if` statement must be failing.

Comment: Umm thanks - didn't notice that! However, it is still not the *only* cause. I'm getting a `NullPointerException` so there's something else going on...

Comment: I guess on your Log line, since I cannot see where `view` is intialised.  However, one question per post please.  Start a new question and be sure to include the stack trace.

Comment: Ha! You just solved my problem! I was checking the tag on `view` (which is not even related), instead of getting the view from the array called `views`. Thank you a bunch!